# Unable to execute perl script in cmd without invoking perl.exe

Tags: perl, cmd

I am trying to execute a perl script to delete file1.txt in a directory. 
When I execute the perl script using command prompt, I faced an error : `Use of uninitialized value in chdir at C:/Debug/test.pl line 7`. 
Example:

```
C:\Debug>test.pl C:\Debug
```

However if I invoke `perl` in front of `test.pl`, the perl script is executed successfully and file1.txt was deleted. 
Example:

```
C:\Debug>perl test.pl C:\Debug
```

Please find `test.pl` code as follow:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my ($working_dir) = @ARGV;
chdir $working_dir or die "Can't change directory$!";
unlink "file1.txt";
```

I have mks_toolkit v8.7.5 with perl.exe installed. The `.pl` extension is associated with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt\perl.exe" "%1" %*`. 
I have no problem execute hello.pl (Hello World) without invoking perl in front of it.
Example:

```
C:\Debug>hello.pl
```

Comment: Hi. What do you get if you add `print "@ARGV\n"` above `my ($working_dir) = @ARGV;` and run the script both ways?

Comment: Hello, I get `Use of uninitialized value in chdir at C:/Debug/test.pl line 7` error w/o invoke perl and  `C:\Debug` output if invoke perl.

Comment: Odd, so when you invoke the script with out `perl` on the command line, the parameters after the script are not being passed to the script. This looks like a problem with how Windows is starting the Perl interpreter not a problem with Perl it's self.

Comment: I tried ActivePerl, I have the same error too. The only Perl that works is Strawberry Perl after I did some minor tweaking on the .pl file properties and open it with Perl interpreter.

Comment: As I said odd, try asking on a specific forum for the version of Perl you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, users who face this problem can try to check the properties of your file, make sure the file is not read only and has full admin access.